# bootstrap: Image in tab messed up with other tab displays

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Well I am trying to put an image to the left of nav tabs, but it seems that something isnt right. The tabs now align to the top of the image, while I want the opposite, the tabs should align to the bottom of image. You can see the screenshot for more details of how its messed up:
[image]

Below are the HTML code I use with bootstrap, anyone know how to solve this display issue?

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
        <li class="nav nav-item"><img src="{$image}" class="img-responsive"></li>
        <li id="atab1" class="nav-item"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active">About</a></li>
        <li id="atab2" class="nav-item"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Posts</a></li>
        <li id="atab3" class="nav-item"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Goods</a></li>
        <li id="atab4" class="nav-item"><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
        <li id="atab5" class="nav-item"><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Jobs</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nav-item {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```